# What regEx can I use to Split a string into whole words but only if they start with #?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have tried this...

```
Dim myMatches As String() = 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(postRow.Item("Post"), "\b\#\b")
```

But it is splitting all words, I want an array of words that start with#

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work...

c#

```
Regex MyRegex = new Regex("\\#\\w+");
MatchCollection ms = MyRegex.Matches(InputText);
```

or vb.net

```
Dim MyRegex as Regex = new Regex("\#\w+")
Dim ms as MatchCollection = MyRegex.Matches(InputText)
```

Given input text of...

"asdfas asdf #asdf asd fas df asd fas #df asd f asdf"

...this will yield....

"#asdf" and "#df"

I'll grant you that this does not get you a string Array but the MatchCollection is enumerable and so might be good enough.

---

Additionally, I'll add that I got this through the use of [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). which appears to be free. It was very helpful in producing the c# which I am very poor at. (Ie it did the escaping for me.)
(If anyone thinks I should remove this pseudo-advert then please comment, but I thought it might be helpful :) Good times )

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to include the words in the split you should use something like

```
"\b#\w+\b"
```

This includes the actual word there in the expression. However I'm not sure that's what you want. Could you provide an example of input and the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$text = 'Test #string testing #my test #text.';
preg_match_all('/#[\S]+/', $text, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
echo '</pre>';
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #string
    [1] => #my
    [2] => #text.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code in Javascript:

```
text = "what #regEx can I use to #split a #string into whole words but only" 
// what #regEx can I use to #split a #string into whole words but only"
text.match(/#\w+/g);
// [#regEx,#split,#string]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft RegEx flavours, try: `\#:w`

That worked for me using Find in Visual Studio.  I don't know how it will translate into the RegEx class.

***EDIT***: Backslash was swallowed.